# Native BLE API in Android

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

The stackoverflow user Wilhelmsen said a few months ago that "Rumors say that Google will release an official API around August 2012". So now it is the end of August, and I was wondering if anyone has any updates on the status of the native BLE API for Android phones - it's not on Jellybeans unfortunately!

Comment: I am working in a company which develops BLE chipsets. As one of the developers said, google doesn't focus on BLE that much because it is not as profitable as NFC. So we just have to wait...

Answer (score 1):

Android API for BLE development is now available with the latest update [API 18].

Check the link http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html

Comment: Android BLE API guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: @Pupsik : Sorry for my bad English. By NATIVE, I mean, Android's own API. :) (And of course, It is in Java) Thanks for pointing out that misleading statement. :) I Corrected It.

Comment: No problem. Just thought that maybe I'm missing something ;)